# Error coming when we try connecting to mysql via SQOOP

Tags: mysql, sqoop

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.initOptionDefaults(MySQLManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.<init>(SqlManager.java:89)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.<init>(SqlManager.java:33)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.<init>(GenericJdbcManager.java:51)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.<init>(GenericJdbcManager.java:30)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.<init>(CatalogQueryManager.java:46)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.<init>(CatalogQueryManager.java:31)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.InformationSchemaManager.<init>(InformationSchemaManager.java:38)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.InformationSchemaManager.<init>(InformationSchemaManager.java:31)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.<init>(MySQLManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory.accept(DefaultManagerFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:272)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:44)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
    at java.net.URLClas`enter code here`sLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in here

```java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
```

It cannot find the class definition of StringUtils, which means you are missing some jar files.

**Edit:**

Please follow the comments in order to download the jar file and include in the environment.

Comment: It'd be useful to mention which files and where to put them

Comment: The missing library is apache commons lang. Can be downloaded from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/ - Note that it looks like it is version 2.6 you need, not version 3.9

Answer (score 0):

Download avro-1.8.2.jar and apache-commons-lang.jar and paste inside your installations common folder (in my case I have pasted in hadoop-3.2.3/share/hadoop/common)

Answer (score 0):

In **version 2.6** it used to be in,

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
```

You just add **common-lang-2.6.jar** file and **common-lang3-3.4.jar** file.

Hope it may be help you.